# PIL.ImageDraw.arc drawing nothing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

PIL.ImageDraw.arc(xy, start, end, fill, width)

xy – Two points to define the bounding box. Sequence of [(x0, y0), (x1, y1)] or [x0, y0, x1, y1], where x1 >= x0 and y1 >= y0.(from [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=arc#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.arc))

My code

```py
image = Image.new('RGBA', (300, 300), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
x0, y0, x1, y1 = (50, 200, 250, 200)
draw.arc((x0, y0, x1, y1), 0, 180, 'red')
print(x1 >= x0 and y1 >= y0) # -> True
```

but image is blank

Comment: Why are you using RGBA?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes

Comment: No. It wasn't a Yes/No question. It was **why**.

Comment: Oh shit, sorry, getting late, anyway, im drawing a smiley for pyqt5 QLabel and I need alpha channel to draw background color @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your bounding box is a problem and you want something more akin to this:

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', (300, 400), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
bbox = (10, 50, 250, 300)
draw.arc(bbox, 0, 180, 'red')
```

[image]